# Returning function result back to DF

Tags: replace, return, in-place

I am trying to replace the "0" and "1" values with "Yes" and "No" in the below dataframe (initially the "Open" column, but want to do others too):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8a7R.png)

```py
def change(int):
    if int == 1:
        return "Yes"
    else:
        return "No"
```

```py
merged_stores[["Open"]].apply(lambda x:change(x["Open"]), axis=1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIp0v.png)

I've tried multiple things, but can not get it to save back to the original df...

Things I've tried:

inplace=True

return merged_stores

creating a new df and using
merged_stores[["Open"]] = newOpen[["Open"]]

After hours of jiggling, still n joy :(

Things I've tried:

inplace=True

return merged_stores

creating a new df and using
merged_stores[["Open"]] = newOpen[["Open"]]

I tried a variety of variations using the above methods, but no joy unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I based it on online apply examples.

```py
import pandas as pd

def number_to_bin(nb):
    return nb == 1

df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9]] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(number_to_bin)
print(df.to_string())
```

```
   A  B
0  4  9
1  4  9
2  4  9

       A  B
0  False  9
1  False  9
2  False  9
```